# How can we use data-table across steps?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, python-behave

We have some category tiles on the home page through which the products are being filtered, say for eg:- Tile 1 belongs to clothes, once clicked the following page should show clothes, Tile 2 belongs to shoes, once clicked the following page should show shoes and so on.

The objective is to click tile1, verify the text and products, click tile 2 verify text and products, and so on.

I want to use a data table to test this scenario

Here is the feature file content:-

```
Scenario Outline: Filtering the products on the home page
    Given the user is on the homepage
    When the user selects the <category> tile for filtering the products
      | category              |
      | cat 1                 |
      | cat 2                 |
      | cat 3                 |
      | cat 4                 |
   Then only the relevant products should be displayed to the user
```

Problem is, I want to click and verify in the same step but with the above setting, I won't be able to do that. Any suggestion/inputs on how this can be done?

Details:- When I click the tile new page will load with the tile text on the left side and relevant products these 2 actions happen one after another and hence I wanted to do this in a same step but doesn't look right in the context of given when and then

Answer (score 0):

If you want to verify for each of the test date, `category` table should be in `Examples`.

```
Scenario Outline: Filtering the products on the home page
    Given the user is on the homepage
    When the user selects the <category> tile for filtering the products
    Then only the relevant products should be displayed to the user

Examples:
      | category              |
      | cat 1                 |
      | cat 2                 |
      | cat 3                 |
      | cat 4                 |
```

Comment: In case of examples it will login those many times. I wanted to perform this with a single login.

Comment: Put the login implementation in a `before` hook in `environment.py`. The login part is probably going to be a prerequisite for other scenarios/features anyway

Comment: There are feature files that won't need login like Sign-up scenarios and hence I kept the login implementation in respective feature files. In some cases, I am using background to log in.

Comment: Than maybe put the login in a Background of the feature files that need it, rather than in the before hook